# How can I get my windows to remember the last window location?

Tags: 11.10, unity, window-manager, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remember last window location](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13975/remember-last-window-location)

I want to ask the [same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13975/remember-last-window-location) for Ubuntu 11.10... how can I configure Ubuntu 11.10 to start all program windows at the last window location? This feature would be really helpful. :)