# Can applications remember last window position?

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu, running Ubuntu 15.10 (Unity) and this is kind of driving me crazy:

Some apps open flush with a certain corner or edge of the screen, some open in the middle of the screen, and almost none of them seem to remember their last location after I close them. Is there a simple way to have all apps remember their last location?

Comment: Possible? like everything, yes, very well possible I would say, but simple? definitely not. It would require a background script to record the last window position (per application), then make *new* windows take that position and size. There is no existing solution as far as I know, unless someone knows differently. The current behaviour differs per application I believe.

Comment: If the application itself does not set it's own position, then the position of newly opened applications depends on what other applications are already running and where they are on the screen. I agree that this is annoying!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember last window location](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13975/remember-last-window-location)

Comment: Although the question is an exact dupe, the answers there do not answer how to remember the *last position* unfortunately.